# Struggling with Perl regex: Extracting scenario blocks from text

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

Im struggling with RegEx but first of all here is my input:

```
 #
  #------------------------------------------- spaceholder ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #

  #@E2E-1 @id:1 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  #@E2E-2 @id:32 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message


  #
  #------------------------------------------- B2B_PKG_3PA ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


  #

  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
```

and this is the output Im trying to archieve:

```
 #@E2E-1 @id:1 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  #@E2E-2 @id:32 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
```

I tried this Pattern on a RegEx test website and it worked so well:

```
((@[^\n]+|#@[^\n]+)?\s*)?Scenario:[^\n]*\n(?:[^\n]*\n)*?\n
```

yet when I use it in perl it doesnt seem to work at all.

This is how I want to use it inside my Code:

```
while (my $block = <$initial_fh>) {
        push @scenarios, $block if ($block =~ /$pattern/);
    }
```

Please help

Comment: It is not clear how you want to apply the regex, i.e. by processing the input line by line or by applying it to a single input string. For line by line when reading from a file the following seem to produce what you want: `perl -ne 'print if !/^\s*#(?!@)/'`. For having everything in a single string: `s/^\s*#(?!@).*\n//mg`; For the details see the topic of lookbehind in [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions)

Comment: sorry I shouldve added this part: while (my $block = <$initial_fh>) {
        push @scenarios, $block if ($block =~ /$pattern/);
    }
i want to push each block into the scenarios array

Comment: Note that `while(<$fh>) { push @scenario, $_ if (/pattern/); }` is nothing more than `my @scenario = grep { /pattern/ } <$fh>;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the input separator, `$/`, to paragraph mode and then only capture the paragraphs beginning with `/^\s*#?@/`. You only use your actual filename in the `open(...` below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $file =<<'EOF';
#
  #------------------------------------------- spaceholder ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #

  #@E2E-1 @id:1 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message



  #@E2E-2 @id:32 
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message


  #
  #------------------------------------------- B2B_PKG_3PA ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


  #

  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
EOF

local $/ = ''; # enable 'paragraph' mode (blocks separated by 2 or more \n)
my @scenarios;

open my $fh, '<', \$file;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push (@scenarios, $_) if /^\s*#?@/;
}

print join "\n\n", @scenarios;
```

Prints:

```
  #@E2E-1 @id:1
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message

  #@E2E-2 @id:32
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_IN >> NL
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message

  @E2E-3 @id:3
  Scenario: Login & Search: B2B_PKG_3PA >> BE
    Given I am on the login page
    When I enter <username> and incorrect password multiple times
    Then I should be locked out of my account
    And I should see a lockout message
```

(NOTE: your code corrected)

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $initial_fh, '<', "initial_state.txt_formatted";
open my $current_fh, '<', "current_state.txt_formatted";

my @scenarios;

{
    local $/ = ''; # enable 'paragraph' mode (restricted to this block)
    while (<$initial_fh>) {
        chomp;
        push (@scenarios, $_) if /^\s*\#?\@/;
    }
}

print join("\n", @scenarios);

close $initial_fh;
close $current_fh;
```